# how do you install ubuntu touch as a desktop environment?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, desktop-environments

On another question someone mentioned that you could install ubuntu touch as a desktop environment for laptops with touchscreens. I have not been able to find this option. Is there a way I could try this out?